# How to make maths explainer videos?

Tags: course-design, interactive-teaching

I am a maths teacher and I want to make maths explainer videos particularly like [this guy is doing.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dyK_op-Ocw) In fact, in my research, I came to know that manim is the latest tool for creating maths animations but it is hard and time-consuming (at least for me) because it requires python and long codes. But I am sure this guy is not using manim. If you know how one can make such videos please let me know.

Possibly, he is using blender but I am not sure as I am new on blender.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you ask the video author?  IME, YouTubers are usually as thrilled to discuss their tools as they are to discuss their content.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Indeed, I asked him too but he did not reply to my email, possibly because he did not notice my mail as he might be getting lot of emails of praise.

Comment: @MatthewDaly From the video description in the posted link: *Like many YouTubers I use popular software to prepare my videos. You can search for animation software tutorials on YouTube to learn how to make videos. Be prepared--animation is time consuming and software can be expensive!* Therefore, it seems this particular YouTuber is not interested in discussing their tools.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that PowerPoint is used, as explained in [this video](https://youtu.be/Ksw0LUVu-Gw).